# Displaying 2 screens side by side when horizontal with react-native-router-flux (RNRF)

Tags: react-native, responsive-design, orientation, responsive, react-native-router-flux

Currently as I am using Redux, so [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/RNRF/react-native-router-flux) is a natural choice of Navigation. (I don't mind using another library if it would be easier)

**Problem:** Imagine an iPad app, when it is vertical, there will be 3 tabs for 3 screens.  When it is horizontal, there will only be 2 tabs, and the landing screen will be "split" in the middle to show the first 2 screens.

**Illustration:**
[image: Illustration]

**What I think:**
I guess I have to duplicate the Routers -- one for portrait and one for landscape.  Duplicate the (responsive) screens (1,2,3) and give them different keys to avoid collision between 2 routers...

**Question:** Is there a way to minimize duplication?  I think there should be one which I create an extra screen, say `index-landscape` and *the number of tabs* and *the component to be rendered* can be controlled programmatically instead of a full duplication of `<Router>`.